# Raster Copy: Output bit size does not match specified value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, copy

Using ArcGIS (Map/Catalog) 10.0.  I have a raster file (kdens) developed from point data using the kernel density tool.  It is 32-bit float file format.  I need this file converted to a polygon shapefile.  (Note I have used the Math/Times tool to preserve the decimal units in a new raster: kdens100K).  Using the copy raster tool, I have specified the output raster to 32-bit unsigned.  However, the output raster is identified as a 16-bit signed when I check the raster properties and the raster values are truncated to match the 16-bit value range.

Any insight into to why the output is being formatted to 16-bit signed when I specify 32-bit unsigned?

Comment: That is unusual. Why are you copying it? If you already have it as a raster... are you changing format? Are you certain the 'to' format supports UInt32 pixel format? i.e. what format is 'from' and what format is 'to'. Here is a link to ArcGis formats and their supported data types http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000q000000

Comment: Raster has to be of integer type if you want to convert it to polygons. Copy raster tool lives in it's own world